# How to have optional filters in mongodb queries

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following document model...

```
{
    _id: 'jr3h4h51gkjfhqd',
    first_name: 'bob',
    last_name: 'jones',
    age: 33,
    email: 'bob@bobby.com',
    phone_number: '',
    job: 'accountant',
    title: 'mr'
}
```

Is there a way I can write a query so that the query will have a filter for a certain value if a filter is provided, otherwise there won't be a filter applied for that property.

If a filter isn't provided, then that filter is left out (essentially, if no filters are provided, then all documents will be returned), but if only one filter is provided, then the query should only filter the documents based on that one filter.
Here is the query if 5 filters are provided.

```
User.find(
  {
    first_name: FIRST_NAME_FILTER,
    last_name: LAST_NAME_FILTER,
    email: EMAIL_FILTER,
    job: JOB_FILTER,
    title: TITLE_FILTER
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in 2 places

1. In the driver
   You can use the driver programming language and generate the query.
   For example

```js
  query={}
  if(first_name_filter) query.add("first_name",first_name_filter);
  if(last_name_filter) query.add("last_name",last_name_filter);
  ...

  User.find(query);
```

2. In the database
   MongoDB offers [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) aggregate operators,and you can do the same using
   aggregation,but if you know that information before you send the query
   there is no reason to do it in the database